# How to create "broken glass" animation?

Tags: unity, c#, animation, random

I have started making a 3D game in Unity5 that consists in avoiding obstacles. It is very easy but I want to add a collision effect when I collide on the wall.

I would like to slice the screen into many parts (random pieces is better) that are falling down from screen with gravity.

**An example of what I mean:**
[image]

How can I do this?
I've tried using a lot of different images (shapes) but I'm sure that is not the best way...

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/81796/how-can-glass-breaking-effect-from-smash-hit-be-achieved

http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18881/how-can-i-simulate-shattering-glass

I believe it was based on voronoi diagrams, but not quite sure

Answer (score 1):

Instead of randomly slicing the sprite, you can create several different animations including premade sliced sprites, and randomly play one of them.

If you have around 5-6, the repeats would be unnoticable for the most of the players.

---

There is also [this asset on the Asset Store](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/12911) which allows you to dynamically slice sprites on runtime.

Comment: it's a good workaround...